# Dynamic bean registration Quarkus

Tags: java, quarkus, cdi, javabeans

Is there any way to initialize bean dynamically through runtime in Quarkus like it's in Spring https://www.baeldung.com/spring-5-functional-beans

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Spring5Application.class)
public class BeanRegistrationIntegrationTest {
    @Autowired
    private GenericWebApplicationContext context;
   
    //...
}

context.registerBean(MyService.class, () -> new MyService());
```

Comment: No. In Quarkus, beans are only registered during application build. Now, your question doesn't really tell, but there is often a way to determine whether you need the bean or not during application build, and register it at that time -- that of course _is_ possible.